# How to PUBLISH to AWS IoT Job

Tags: python, aws-sdk, aws-iot

Didn't get the message of $aws/things/thingName/jobs/get/accepted or rejected.

I created a simple AWS IoT job.

I subscribed `$aws/things/+/jobs/get/accepted`, `$aws/things/+/jobs/get/rejected`, `$aws/things/+/jobs/update`, `$aws/things/+/jobs/update/accepted`, `$aws/things/+/jobs/update/rejected` on IoT console.

I kicked jobsSample.py in AWS IoT SDK.

The job completed successfully.

I expecting to receive any messages via these topics.

But IoT console detected nothing.

In case of ClientId instead of `+`, same.

```
python jobsSample.py -e endpoint -r rootca -c crt -k key -id id -n id
```

I got messages via `$aws/things/(ClientId)/jobs/notify-next` and `$aws/things/(ClientId)/jobs/notify`.